# Collection#removeIf different behavior between JDKs

Tags: java, collections, java-8

With Tomcat 9.0.39 running on JDK 11.0.10.

or with Tomcat 8.5.65 running on JDK 1.8.0_271.

The following code, compiled with JDK 1.8.0_271, is running fine.

```
final Set<A> a = _a.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());

a.removeIf(b -> 
    Objects.nonNull(b.getOne()) 
    && Objects.nonNull(b.getTwo()) 
    && Objects.nonNull(b.getThree())
    && Objects.nonNull(b.getFour())
);
```

However, the `removeIf` part is not executed with the following configurations (next opreations were executed on all elements of `_a` list) :

- Tomcat 8.5.59 running on JDK 1.8.0_202-b08.
- Tomcat 8.5.34 running on JDK 1.8.0_191.

To reach the expected result everywhere, `removeIf` has been replaced by a filter :

```
final Set<A> a = _a.stream()
    .filter(b -> 
        Objects.isNull(b.getOne()) 
        && Objects.isNull(b.getTwo()) 
        && Objects.isNull(b.getThree())
        && Objects.isNull(b.getFour())
    )       
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

or with a Supplier :

```
final Set<A> a = _a.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));

a.removeIf(b -> 
    Objects.nonNull(b.getOne()) 
    && Objects.nonNull(b.getTwo()) 
    && Objects.nonNull(b.getThree())
    && Objects.nonNull(b.getFour())
);
```

I've read about [Collectors#toSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet--) or [Collectors#toList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) :

> Returns a Collector that accumulates the input elements into a new Set / List. There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the Set / List returned; if more control over the returned Set / List is required, use toCollection(Supplier).

But here where are not in parallel stream, the stream is collected with the terminal operation in a final set and [Collection#removeIf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) was introduced in JDK 1.8.

So my question is :

**Why does it behave differently on different JDK minor versions?**

**(or at least it doesn't work as expected with JDK <= 1.8.0_271)**

---

Q/A

**What happens if you replace _a.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet()); with new HashSet<>(_a)?**

Same thing, working on the working configuration, not working on the other one and printing elements that shouldn't be remaining in the set.

```
final Set<A> a = new HashSet<>(_a);
```

**Is this behavior "random" (as in the title), meaning this happens sometimes but not always ; or merely unexpected, meaning this happens always on particular JDK versions, but you're just not sure why?**

This happens always on particular JDK versions, but I am just not sure why. Before 1.8.0_271 the `removeIf` never gets executed (several tries to be sure), after or with this version, it always filter the elements (several tries too).

**Does A implement equals and hashCode correctly?**

Class A is implementing `java.lang.Comparable<A>` like this :

```
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (o instanceof A) {
        A a = (A o;
        result = 
            getId1() == a.getId1()
            && getId2() == a.getId2()
            && getId3() == a.getId3();
    }
    return result;
}
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
 */
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(getId1());
    sb.append(getId2());
    sb.append(getId3());
    return sb.hashCode();
}
/* 
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Comparable#compareTo(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public int compareTo(A a) {
    return 
        getId1() == a.getId1() 
        && getId2() == a.getId2() 
        && getId3() == a.getId3() 
        ? 1 : 0;
}
```

**How do you determine that the code has not been executed?**

The first way I used was the table in the production database, it got all the elements updated whereas it should only get the elements of the reduced set updated. This shows me the error.
Then, the second way I used to be sure was a simple `printf` like this, after commenting the database methods which updates the table.

```
a.stream()
    .filter(b -> 
        Objects.nonNull(b.getOne()) 
        || Objects.nonNull(b.getTwo()) 
        || Objects.nonNull(b.getThree()) 
        || Objects.nonNull(b.getFour())
    )
    .forEach(a -> 
        System.out.printf(
            "%nbad elements remaining in the set : %s%n", 
            a.getId1()
        )
    );
```

And the printed results, were various on the configuration where it doesn't work (production) : sometimes 300 items were updated, sometimes 400.
On the working configuration (development), nothing got printed. This pointed out the fact it works differently on JDKs.

**Just use **`Objects.hash(getId1(), getId2(), getId3());`** there is no reason to use expensive string concatenation. But your compareTo method is broken as well. A comparison method must be symmetric (yours is not), transitive (yours is not), creating a total order for all objects (yours is not even trying). Your way of determine whether this intermediate step did what it should do, is insufficient as well. You didn’t even verify whether the set had the intended content, before applying the filter.**

I have replaced the following implementations of `java.lang.Comparable<A>#compareTo` and `java.lang.Object#hashCode`.

`hashCode`

```
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
 */
/*@Override
public int hashCode() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(getId1());
    sb.append(getId2());
    sb.append(getId3());
    return sb.hashCode();
}*/

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
 */
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(getId1(), getId2(), getId3());
}
```

`compareTo`

```
/* 
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Comparable#compareTo(java.lang.Object)
 */
/*@Override
public int compareTo(A a) {
    return 
        getId1() == a.getId1() 
        && getId2() == a.getId2() 
        && getId3() == a.getId3() 
        ? 1 : 0;
}*/

/* 
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Comparable#compareTo(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public int compareTo(A a) {
    int result;
    if (a.getId2() != getId2()) {
        throw new ClassCastException(
            String.format(
                "a A with id2 euqals to %s cannot be compared with "
                + "another A with id2 equals to %s", 
                getId2(), 
                a.getId2()
            )
        );
    }
    if (
        getId1() == a.getId1() 
        && getId2() == a.getId2()
        && getId3() == a.getId3()
    ) {
        result = 0;
    }
    else if (getId1() < a.getId1()) {
        result = 1;
    }
    else {
        result = -1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I can confirm it is now working fine on every JDK (1.8.0_191, 1.8.0_202, 1.8.0_271, 11.0.10) and on every version of Tomcat (8.5.34, 8.5.59, 8.5.65, 9.0.39).

While this doesn't explain why it ***worked*** (if I can say so) on JDK 1.8.0_271 and above, the answer to this strange behavior was a bad implementation of `java.lang.Object#hashCode` and `java.lang.Comparable#compareTo` methods.

Comment: What happens if you replace `_a.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());` with `new HashSet<>(_a)`?

Comment: Does `A` implement `equals` and `hashCode` correctly? I'd be surprised if not doing so stopped a `HashSet` from being able to iterate all its elements (or remove an element); but that's the most obvious difference that springs to mind between `HashSet` and `TreeSet`.

Comment: Also: is this behavior "random" (as in the title), meaning this happens sometimes but not always; or merely unexpected, meaning this happens always on particular JDK versions, but you're just not sure why?

Comment: `Collectors.toSet()` does not guaranty that the returned set is mutable. But since it always is a `HashSet` in these implementations, the actual question is: “how do you determine that the code has not been executed?”. And your `filter` predicate is *not* the negation of the `removeIf` predicate.

Comment: Looks like A::hashCode depends on StringBuilder::hashCode, which is in fact the identity hash code inherited from Object::hashCode. That is, SB's hashCode is based on the object identity, not on its contents. Since A::hashCode allocates a new SB each time it's called, it will probably return a different value each time. The identity hash code can differ from run to run and from JDK release to release, this is what probably is leading to a bunch of weird behavior with HashSet.

Comment: @StuartMarks Thanks for your answer, so what do you advise ? What hashcode implementation would you advise to make it work the same way on every JDK release?

Comment: Just use [`Objects.hash(getId1(), getId2(), getId3())`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash-java.lang.Object...-); there is no reason to use expensive string concatenation. But your `compareTo` method is broken as well. A comparison method must be *symmetric* (yours is not), *transitive* (yours is not), creating a total order for all objects (yours is not even trying). Your way of determine whether this intermediate step did what it should do, is insufficient as well. You didn’t even verify whether the set had the intended content, before applying the filer.

Comment: @StuartMarks @Holger I edited the question. Changing the `hashCode` bad implementation and incidentally the `compareTo` bad implementation solved the problem.